# Changing the default behavior of where files are saved in windows

Tags: windows, filesystems

Kind of a Admin question - I know.
Here's the thing.

The OS has this deep, strange assumsion that a user wants all there pictures in one folder, all there doc files in another folder - etc. Saveing files based on file type - not the folder in which it was opened.

I, like many business/dev users have my drive devided into folders based on 'projects'.
All 'SmithProject' images goes in SmithProject, All JonesProject Images goes in JoneProject.

Why do I spend so much time fighting the OS when it wants to save all files into a folder based on file type? (No - windows - I don't want it in the pictures folder)

Is there not some simple way / setting to define how this works?

I figure, I loose 1-2 hours a week - just because i have to nav back to the same folder, again & again & again.

Any Pluggin?

Anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without changing special folders locations (My Documents, etc) it could be hard to achieve. Normally in app, when You call OpenFileDialog You can specify where to start (f.ex: always c:\, last opened folder, special folder) and there is no power in the universe to change this.